# "Let us continue this discussion in chat" no more?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat

I looked around a bit and didn't find any information **of any new update regarding this**.

So recently, when I was answering on StackOverflow, after exchanging some comments with the OP, I realized the *"Let us continue this discussion in chat"* won't popup anymore (more recently [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23043143/2513523)). Because of this, I once even had to create an own chatroom for discussion with the OP, which I feel is tedious.

Thus, I'm left wondering:

- What happened to this feature?
- Is it hidden only in cases where the OP won't be able to enter chat due to their insufficient reputation or removed totally?
- Has anyone seen a blog post or another thread about this?

PS: This may look like a good move and I understand the reason why chatrooms need to be avoided, but it's also a fact you come across questions where you need to have a lot of verbal exchange before the problem could be pinpointed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would love to hear why someone felt the need to down-vote my question.

Comment: The feature still exists with no changes that I'm aware of. Can you link to the post where you expected to see it?

Comment: @AnnaLear I have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, I haven't seen this pop up today either, even in cases of prolonged (and sometimes rancorous) discussion. I think that user007 might be on to something. 1+

Comment: I wonder if it's been changed so the other person needs to have enough rep for chat? I seem to remember it used to come up regardless and then you couldn't invite them.

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Can I get your permission to impersonate you on Stack Overflow for a minute? I won't do anything actively; just want to see what you see.

Comment: @balpha Didn't know mods could do that, well go ahead.

Comment: Mods cannot do that. Developers can (although it's not very easy); just don't want to do it without the user's consent. It's not like we would see secret things that we couldn't see otherwise, but it's just not right to do it without asking.

Comment: @balpha You have my consent then. Feel free to hop into my account if it would help in solving.

Comment: Bug reproduced; dropping out of your shoes again :)

Comment: I too felt this when I was [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23006021/3330969).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Good catch, this was a bug. We were checking for an ongoing discussion only during the initial page load, not when fetching all comments after clicking "add/show more". Given that the check is only made when no comments are hidden, that more than 5 comments aren't displayed during the initial page load, and that you need six comments to trigger the discussion check, that was pretty useless.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Well done and thank you!

Comment: It still does't work. Maybe it doesn't work on answers?

Comment: Please, please drop the heuristic already and allow anyone with sufficient privileges to move (select) comments to a (maybe new) chatroom.

Comment: I created a feature-request: [Option to continue a discussion in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233548)

Comment: i don't see doing this comment how can I invite you to the chat..., I see only help and "add comment" button...